# What is a constant morphism of schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I am dealing with some basic notions on schemes and I was asking myself what does it mean for a morphism between two schemes 
$$f:(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$$
to be constant. The obvious answer is that $f(X)$ is reduced to a point $\{y\}$, however I was wondering what happens on the level of the sheaf morphism:
$$f^\#:\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow f_*\mathcal{O}_X$$
Now for any open $U\subseteq Y$, one has
$$f_*\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\left\{\begin{array}[c],
X\text{ if }y\in U\\
\emptyset\text{ if }y\notin U
\end{array}\right.$$
thus ignoring the canonically zero maps $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)\rightarrow f_*\mathcal{O}_X(U)=0$, when $y\notin U$, this amounts to a system of maps
$\big(\mathcal{O}_Y(U)\rightarrow
f_*\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)\big)_{y\in U}$ compatible with restriction, ie a morphism
$$\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(X)$$
thus à priori there are more than just one constant morphism with image $\{y\}$.
Am I missing something? If not, are there some classic examples that can illustrate this fact? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I'm no specialist, but why would it be a problem for there to be multiple constant morphisms ?

Comment: @Max No problem at all, I was just trying to make sense of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not the right definition. In any category with a terminal object $1$, a constant morphism is a morphism that factors through the terminal object. In particular there is exactly one such morphism $X \to Y$ for every global point $1 \to Y$; note that these are very different from points of the Zariski spectrum, for schemes, because the terminal object is $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$, and in particular there often won’t be any. E.g. with this definition there are no constant morphisms if $Y$ is the spectrum of a field.

The [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+morphism) also suggests another definition which is slightly weaker.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu. I first thought of constant morphisms, when doing an exercise involving projective spaces over a filed $K$: the only morphisms $\mathbb{P}^m\to\mathbb{P}^n$ with $m>n$  are the constant ones. I also encountered in Liu p.137 Cor. 3.10 an implied definition as the one I talk about. Which definition is this exercise implying? Thanks again!

Comment: For schemes over a field $K$ the terminal object is $\text{Spec } K$ so the two definitions become closer anyway.